# windows server 2008 dns: adding zone for existing external domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

Our local domain is set up as `domainname.local`. Our web assets are hosted remotely by a third party (`domainname.com`).

Currently, there is only 1 Forward Lookup Zone on the machine (`domainname.local`).

I need to add an entry for subdomain (`sub.dominname.com`) that points to a local server (10.0.0.22).

I tried adding another .com zone and set the nameservers to external DNS (8.8.8.8) with an A record pointing the subdomain to 10.0.0.22, but that failed. Well, technically, the sub resolved correctly, but the rest of the .com stopped working (nslookup failed with a "no answer").

Any ideas for a simple way to set this up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to set up split DNS, you need to take ownership of the records in the internal zone that you need the A record for.

In theory, you should be able to add a stub zone for domainname.com and then add a record for sub.domainname.com, but in practice I have found this to be unstable in the long run.

The better solution is just to duplicate the external zone file in a primary zone on your internal DNS servers, and then change the A records that you want to point to internal IP addresses, and add any subdomains that you require.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what it is you did, based on what you've stated in your question, but here's what you can do:

1. Create a new zone on your internal DNS server for the sub-domain (the child domain).
2. Create an empty A record (a domain A record) for the ip address that you want the subdomain to resolve to.
3. You don't need to do anything with external DNS, forwarders, etc., etc. Your internal server will be authoritative for the  child domain only and your current third party DNS servers will continue to be authoritative for the parent domain, from the perspective of internal DNS clients, which is what I gather you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: This seems to work fine for me, no need to duplicate the external zone file or anything like that.

Comment: +1 This answer was helpful for me, as I wanted to change the internal resolution of single host name without having to define all hosts in the zone.